# Output should be no data found

Tags: php, mysql, database

Here i am making a project into this when I search by date. I want to output `no data found` if there is no result. But here I get the table format if there is no results. If data present its OK! but there is the problem is when no data in database.

```
 <?php
include('connect.php');
  ?>
  <?php
 // echo $res;
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM buyer where date='$res'");
//$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM buyer WHERE date='09-01-14'");

if($result==NULL)
{
    echo "no data found";
}
else{
echo "<table class='CSSTable'>

<tr>
<th>invoice no</th>
<th>Buyer Name</th>
<th>Buyer Order number</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Total Amount</th>
<th>Total Items</th>
<th>Generate PDF</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['invoice_number'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['buyer_name'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['buyer_order_number'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['total_amount'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['total_items'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" ." <a href='get_pdf.php?id={$row['invoice_number']}' target='_blank'><img src='image/download.png' width='16' height='16' /></a>" . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }

echo "</table>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: try `$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);` and check if $num > 0

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Answer (score 1):

You should be checking the number of rows returned in the result, using the [`num_rows`](https://www.php.net/mysqli_num_rows). Like so:

```
if(!$result->num_rows)
{
    echo "no data found";
}
```

The `num_rows` will always return an integer number of rows returned.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you called `mysqli_query` with a line that looks like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($query);
```

`mysqli_query` will only **return `false` *if* it fails while executing the query**.  It will not return `false` if the query is successfully executed and has no rows selected (as is probably in your case).  You can reference the documentation on `mysqli_query` [found here](http://php.net/mysqli_query).

What you want to do, instead, is to determine if the `$result` of the successfully executed query has any data rows.  To do this, you can call `mysqli_num_rows($result)`.  This will return to you the number of rows returned by the query.  If this is equal to 0, then this is the 'no data' scenario that you want to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Try by checking the number of rows returned using `mysqli_num_rows()`

```
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($num == 0)
{
echo "no data found";
}
else
{
//do something

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mysqli_num_rows()` to count the number of rows in the result like the following

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
//there are records
}
else{
//no records found
}
```